# How to get complete friend list i.e., people using/not using app through facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Android: Currently using facebook sdk 3.22 version

I've tried searching for this on all available links regarding this topic but dint find a proper solution

I tried to get friend list with taggable_friends api, got the friend list but want to get unique id of that user to store it on my server.

"invitable_friends" API will helps to get friend list but i don't want to use canvas in my application. So is there any alternative for this to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If it´s only for storing the IDs, **there is no way to get ALL friends anymore**. `taggable_friends` is for tagging friends only and `invitable_friends` is for inviting friends to a canvas game:

> The invitable_friends API is only available for games that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation.

This has been discussed in countless threads already, for example: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)